# How to mock BulkResponse class of ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, mockito

How do I mock the implementation for the below method, I am unable to mock BulkResponse.

```
public void aferBulk(long id, BulkRequest bulkRequest, BulkResponse bulkResponse) {
    if(bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
        logFailedResponses(bulkResponse);
    }else {
        //some action
    }
}

private void logFailedBulkItems(BulkResponse bulkResponse) {
     for (BulkItemResponse bulkItemResponse : bulkResponse) {
            if (bulkItemResponse.isFailed()) {
                BulkItemResponse.Failure failure = bulkItemResponse.getFailure();
                LOGGER.error("ES索引失败: {}", failure.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
}
```

I have attempted this, But, i am unable to mock the below line

```
 for (BulkItemResponse bulkItemResponse : bulkResponse)
```

Mocking code:

```
 public void TestMethod(){
    BulkResponse bulkResponse = mock(BulkResponse.class);
    when(bulkResponse.hasFailures()).thenReturn(true);
    when(response.hasFailures()).thenReturn(responseHasFailures);
    BulkItemResponse item1 = mock(BulkItemResponse.class);
    BulkItemResponse item2 = mock(BulkItemResponse.class);
    when(item1.getItemId()).thenReturn(1);
    when(item1.isFailed()).thenReturn(true);
    BulkItemResponse.Failure failure = mock(BulkItemResponse.Failure.class);
    when(failure.getMessage()).thenReturn("Bad message");
    when(item1.getFailure()).thenReturn(failure);
    when(item2.getItemId()).thenReturn(2);
    when(item2.isFailed()).thenReturn(false);
    when(response.getItems()).thenReturn(new BulkItemResponse[]{item1, item2});
}
```

Comment: Mocking such complex clients as ElasticSearch could be very complex. I would suggest to consider [Elasticsearch container](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/elasticsearch/) from [testcontainers.org](http://www.testcontainers.org) as an embedded Elasticsearch for tests. 

The advantage is that you could use any version of Elasticsearch and it's pretty easy to integrate into any project.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem specifically with mocking iterating in a `for` loop.

`for` loop can be used on classes that implement `Iterable` interface, as it uses its method `iterator()`. You would need to mock this method of your `BulkResponse` with an iterator of a list that contains your instances of `BulkItemResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier not to mock it. Just use a real instance of `BulkResponse`.

In this case, mocking is more trouble than it's worth. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/bulk/BulkResponse.java) for that class, all you've got to do is create a new `BulkResponse` with your `BulkResponseItem` as the argument.

So just do this instead. It'll be much cleaner:

```
new BulkResponse(new BulkItemResponse[]{item1, item2}, 1L);
```

If you *really* want to, that class implements the `Iterable` interface, so you need to mock the `iterator()` method. The for each loop actually calls `iterator()`.